# pivot table syntax with correct header order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table I want to pivot:

```
name | val 1 | val 2
a    |  1    |   2
b    |  4    |   4
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
  a                b
 val 1 | val 2 | val 1 | val 2
  1    |   2   |  4    |   4
```

however, using the pivot table function in pandas gives me this:

```
  a         b       a      b 
 val 1 | val 1 | val 2 | val 2
  1    |   4   |  2    |   4
```

Comment: what pivot table function gives you that output?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df.set_index('name').T.unstack().to_frame().T

name    a               b
        val1    val2    val1    val2
0       1       2       4       4
```